# Asp.net 2008 Express Book Recommendation

Tags: asp.net

### Requirements

- Practical
- Asp.net on Asp.net 2008 Express
- Environment Perspective

Answer (score 1):

Since Visual Web Developer 2008 EE is really just a subset of Visual Studio I don't think there are any books that focus just on the express version. Most of the beginner/intermediate books you read will be relevant to the express version even if the author assumes you have VS 2005 or 2008.
That said, if you really want something that has the express version in mind I think [learnvisualstudio.net](http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/) is the way to go for beginner level instruction. Good luck!